# Angular2 use QueryList, parent inject in the children Error: Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: angular

In the parent

```
@ContentChildren(UiselectItemComponent) items: QueryList<UiselectItemComponent>;
```

in the children

```
constructor(private uiselect: UiselectComponent) {}
```

I've got Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UiselectItemComponent: (?).

Can anyone tell me what's the problem, please ?

Comment: Can you show more code? You probably declare UiselectComponent after component where you use it in constructor

Comment: You can try using forwardref or change your application structure

Comment: Or you have a circular dependencies

Comment: Thanks fo the hint the first one doesn't work, I'll try with forwardref  but I think to change application structure like tabs https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html

Comment: You probably declare UiselectComponent after component what do you mean ? I've posted more code

Comment: Please show more code that makes it clear what parent is and what child is. Why do you think injecting UiselectComponent in your example should work?

Comment: `what do you mean ?` https://plnkr.co/edit/Nwd1sIU8ibBYyUeDtPu6?p=preview See console.

Comment: Thanks for the help here it is https://plnkr.co/edit/u3dxm9iwJsaauE3V1Ud6?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/3qGqJ0nQ6CiuWtpBKxJ7?p=preview I used there `Inject+forwardRef`

Comment: @Whisher, this might be helpful [What is `forwardRef` in Angular and why we need it](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-forwardref-in-angular-and-why-we-need-it-6ecefb417d48)